# Getting this error when scraping JSON with scrapy: Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

I am trying to get a json field with key "longName" with scrapy but I am receiving the error: "Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str'".

The JSON I'm trying to scrape looks something like this:

```
{
   "id":5355,
   "code":9594,
```

}sadsadsd

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json

class NotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'notes'
    allowed_domains = ['blahblahblah.com']
    start_urls = ['https://blahblahblah.com/api/123']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        yield from data['longName']
```

I get the above error when I run "scrapy crawl notes" in prompt. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and [mre]. We can only help you with a proper understanding of the problem (which comes out of your best attempt to fix it yourself first), the ability to observe the problem ourselves, and a *specific question* - "Please help!" does not qualify.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry. I am completely new to webscraping so if someone can point me in the right direction here. Why am I getting this error? To me I am just requesting that key 'longName' from the JSON be scraped.

Comment: Your level of experience does not matter to the question. The question cannot be answered until you read, understand and apply the advice in the links I gave you. I linked them for a reason. We cannot tell you why you are getting the error because finding out why you get the error requires information that you have not given us. By reading the links, you will understand what information is missing and how to provide it. It is not possible to tell you these things directly in the comments, because it requires too many words.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel maybe I have low IQ but what further information is required on my end? I think i provided enough context as well as the code i've tried.

Comment: Did you read the links? Did you try to fix the problem yourself, like I suggested - specifically by following advice given in one of those links? You *managed all of that in seven minutes*, but you're still totally confused as to what I'm talking about? (Hint: when you look at the link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146, what is the title for that question? "Why should I..." - *did you do the thing* described in the rest of that sentence?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks. I dont want to post the entire error message because some of that information is confidential.

Comment: You can redact file paths. If the problem has to do with sensitive data, then try to create a small new example data set - which you should do anyway, as explained in one of the original set of links - and see what happens with that. If the project involves third-party code that you can't show us, then try (as explained in the same link) to create an example without that part. If it really is essential to the problem, per your investigation, then it is not possible to help you here. We can only diagnose code that we can actually see.

Comment: Separately, you are expected to try to understand the problem. For example, you report an error message reading `Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'str'"`. What thing in the program do you think is the 'str' being complained about? (Did you try to figure out the answer to that? Start by reading backwards through the error traceback.) Where is it being "returned"? (You do understand what that means?) Can you think of a reason why such restrictions exist? (Did you try reading the documentation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want `longName` modifying your parse method like this should do the trick:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        yield {"longName": data["longName"]}
```

Comment: `json.loads` transforms a string into a dict which you can just yield. Meaning just replace `yield {"longName": data["longName"]}` with `yield data`